# Convert 3 different int values within String mode separated by spaces or something else

Tags: java, string, variables, integer, int

I am very new to Java and i want to learn how to do this.

I want to display something like this: **123-45-6789** in a `String` mode by **3** different `int` numbers.

First number by 3 digits.
Second number by 2 digits.
third number by 4 digits.

How can i do this by putting all those numbers together separated by "-"?

I have tried some `string myString = myInt.ToString();` codes that i have found here and there but it doesn't working :/

Here is my code i tried to do it:

```
public void getSsnNumber()
    {
        int valueOfNumber1 = 0;
        int valueOfNumber2 = 0;
        int valueOfNumber3 = 0;
        while (valueOfNumber1 <= 99)
        {
            Random randomNumbers1 = new Random();
            int ssnRandomNumber1 = randomNumbers1.nextInt(999);
            valueOfNumber1 = ssnRandomNumber1;
        }
        while (valueOfNumber2 <= 9)
        {
            Random randomNumbers2 = new Random();
            int ssnRandomNumber2 = randomNumbers2.nextInt(99);
            valueOfNumber2 = ssnRandomNumber2;
        }
        while (valueOfNumber3 <= 999)
        {
            Random randomNumbers3 = new Random();
            int ssnRandomNumber3 = randomNumbers3.nextInt(9999);
            valueOfNumber3 = ssnRandomNumber3;
        }
        String finalNumber = ("%d-%d-%d",valueOfNumber1, valueOfNumber2, valueOfNumber3);
        CommissionEmployee.ssndb = String.valueOf(finalNumber);
        System.out.printf("Ssndb number is: %s", CommissionEmployee.ssndb);
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could improve the code by doing randoms like this: Random randomNumbers1 = new Random();
valueOfNumber1 = randomNumbers1.nextInt(899)+100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.format is what you need, here the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

```
int n1 = 10;
int n2 = 20;
int n3 = 30;

//do some random things

String finalNumber = String.format("%d-%d-%d", n1, n2, n3);
System.out.println("Ssndb number is: " + finalNumber);
```

Comment: OP appears to be generating U.S. Social Security Numbers (SSN), which have fixed `NNN-NN-NNNN` format, so you'd generally want to use the formatting string `"%03d-%02d-%04d"`.  OP has neatly skirted this issue by avoiding numbers that would need zero-filling...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**String.join**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) for example :

```
String[] str = {"123", "45", "6789"};
String result = String.join("-", str);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
123-45-6789
```